# Rendering checkbox in PDF Report

Tags: genexus

I need to show checked and unchecked checkboxes in a PDF report, generated with GeneXus.
The checkbox layout (checked or unchecked) depends by the boolean value of the relative variable.
How I can do that?
I'm using a Procedure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be this:

- include two image in the project (unchecked checkbox and checked checkbox)
- adding one image variable in the procedure for each checkbox
- putting the image variable in the report layout
- change the image in the variable with code like this:

  if(&booleanVariable)
   &imageVariable.FromImage(checked_Image)
  else
   &imageVariable.FromImage(unchecked_Image)
  endif

I hope this can be useful for you.